While implementing mRCNN, experiencing issue with "No module named 'keras.engine'"
I am trying to implement mRCNN, and while trying to utilize it with Keras 2.0, I have repeatedly had the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Warre\PycharmProjects\test3\main.py", line 3, in 
import mrcnn.model
File "C:\Users\Warre\PycharmProjects\CricketAIMonitoring\venv\lib\site-packages\mask_rcnn-2.1-py3.10.egg\mrcnn\model.py", line 23, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.engine'
arise.
I so far have purely tried to get the project at this link: https://github.com/EashanKaushik/car-damage-detecting-MaskRCNN/blob/main/README.md
to function, as well as the demo projects with the balloons in the main github directory, but have had the same issue across the board.
Thank you in advance for your help!

mask_rcnn package is outdated. If you need the model import it from torchvision:
# Packages that I'm using
# torch Version: 2.3.0
# torch Version: 0.18.0

from torchvision.models.detection import MaskRCNN_ResNet50_FPN_Weights, maskrcnn_resnet50_fpn
import torch


# model = maskrcnn_resnet50_fpn(weights=MaskRCNN_ResNet50_FPN_Weights.DEFAULT)
model = maskrcnn_resnet50_fpn(weights=MaskRCNN_ResNet50_FPN_Weights.COCO_V1)

model.eval()
x = [torch.rand(3, 300, 400), torch.rand(3, 500, 400)]
predictions = model(x)

